# Service OnStartCommand calls again while Kill the process

Tags: android, service, android-service, scheduled-tasks

I'm  developing an app that has a recurring task of sending call to the server and check whether the data is available for current date. I have implemented this successfully but I have an issue, when I kill the Process it's call the `service` again. I have monitored this through `Logcat` or it generate the PUSH notification too even the flag is not false (According to my logic). Why because I'm using `*START_STICKY*`?

I have used `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` **flag** too, it solved that issue but in the TaskManager of my cellphone my service status is on *RESTART* when I killed the process. Does the service is still running or it is in *RESTART* state?

I want my service run 24/7 without *RESTART*. either I kill the process like (weChat, Whatsapp, Viber) etc.

Can someone please sort out what I'm doing wrong? or give me the right direction. Help should be appreciated. Thanks

**Service:**

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
         // Log.e("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
            Log.e("AlertService", "Alert-----Service Created");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
                      (new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                            // call service
                             DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                currentDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                                String[] separated_currentDate = currentDate.split("-");
                                int actual_date = Integer.parseInt(separated_currentDate[0]);


                                Log.e("CurrentDate of my Device", currentDate); 
                                Log.e("ad",""+actual_date);

                                if(flag == false)
                                {
                                    Log.e("Flag-Status", "FALSE");
                                    try {
                                        savingDateinPref(currentDate);
                                        isInternetPresent = cm.isConnected();
                                        if(isInternetPresent)
                                        {
                                            Log.e("Flag-Status", "Calling Service");
                                            new DoInBackground().execute(currentDate);
                    //                      currentDate = null;
                                        }

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

                                String val = prefs.getString("TAG_KEY", "defvalue");
                                String[] separated_val = val.split("-");
                                int pref_date = Integer.parseInt(separated_val[0]);
                                Log.e("pd", "" +pref_date);

                                if( (pref_date != actual_date) || ( pref_date < actual_date) || (pref_date > actual_date) ) 
                                {
                                flag = false;
                                Log.e("Flag-Status", "FALSE/bcoz date has been changed");
//                              String empty = null;
//                              savingDateinPref(empty);
                                }

                         }
                      }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

    }
```